# Repitition of selected item in dropdownlist in PHP

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have this problem that the selected value in my dropdownlist is showing twice. What should i do so that it will show only once.

```
 <td>
    <select class="span8" style="width:100%" name="from_time[]" id="from_time<?php echo $count;?>"  value="start_from" onchange="calculate_by_ajax(this.id);">
        <option value="<?php 
        $start_from=$jobs_result['start_from']; 
        //$date_arr_to= explode(" ", $start_from);
        //$date_to= $date_arr_to[0];
        //$time_to= $date_arr_to[1];
        $sec="SELECT DATE_FORMAT('$start_from', '%H:%i') as tp";
        $sec_exe=mysql_query($sec);
        $sec_res=mysql_fetch_array($sec_exe);
        ?>" selected="selected">
        <?php echo $sec_res['tp']; ?></option>
        <?php include("list.php"); ?>           
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Please add more code to the question, I can't make out what's happening. Also please format the code properly

Comment: <td><select class="span8" style="width:100%" name="from_time[]" id="from_time<?php echo $count;?>"  value="start_from" onchange="calculate_by_ajax(this.id);"><option value="<?php       $start_from=$jobs_result['start_from'];          $sec="SELECT DATE_FORMAT('$start_from', '%H:%i') as tp";
            $sec_exe=mysql_query($sec);            $sec_res=mysql_fetch_array($sec_exe);            ?>" selected="selected">            <?php echo $sec_res['tp']; ?></option>
<?php include("list.php"); ?>   
   </select>  </td>

Comment: i added this code above also but i isn't showing.

Comment: The problem is that i want to show the selected time only once in the dropdownlist, but in this case it is showing twice. the selected value is coming from another php page.

Comment: You can fix the formatting by adding all of that to the post, highlighting all the code, and clicking the "Code Sample" button. It looks like this on the editor: {}

Comment: I can't see why it's not working. Can you var_dump the values in $start_from, and $sec_res please? Also, what is in list.php and why are you including it in the middle of the drop down list?

Comment: I'd like to see the code for calculate_by_ajax too

Comment: function calculate_by_ajax(id)
 {         id = id.replace ( /[^0-9.]/g, '' );
    from_time = document.getElementById("from_time"+id).value;
 jobs_mins = document.getElementById("jobs_mins"+id).value; 
$.post("ajax_calculate_time.php",{from_time:from_time,jobs_mins:jobs_mins},function(data)
      {
      //   alert(counter);
      document.getElementById('to_time'+id).value=data;
     
      });
      }

Comment: i have time listed in list.php eg.
<option>01:00</option>
<option>02:00</option>

the $start_from is fetching the value from another php page and the time value is automatically selected on the basis of that page but that time is coming twice eg. if the selected time is 5:30 then it is coming on the top of the list as well as in between the list and i want to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, instead of modifying one of the available options and marking it as selected, you actually add another option with your code.

You could change list.php to look like this (i.e. an array of all the times)

```
<?php 
    $drop_down_values = array('11:35', '11:36', '11:27'); 
?>
```

Then your code should look like this:

```
<?php 
    include("list.php");
    $start_from=$jobs_result['start_from']; 
    $sec="SELECT DATE_FORMAT('$start_from', '%H:%i') as tp";
    $sec_exe=mysql_query($sec);
    $sec_res=mysql_fetch_array($sec_exe);
?>
<td>
    <select class="span8" style="width:100%" name="from_time[]" id="from_time<?php echo $count;?>"  value="start_from" onchange="calculate_by_ajax(this.id);">
        <?php foreach ($drop_down_values as $value) {
            if ($value == $sec_rec) { 
                echo "<option selected=\"selected\">$value</option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option>$value</option>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It will work this way. Its a great help. Thanks alot.

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. You can see how here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow